# How to fix TextView position when text in it changes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout like in this picture below, containing a title, some text view, and a list view. Title is aligned with the top of the screen, and list is aligned with bottom of the screen and should take as much space as possible.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:text="Some random text which can change"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/list_wrapper"
        android:layout_below="@id/some_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After activity is created, text in text view below title can dynamically change, and when it happens it could shrink and list view could change its size. I want to prevent this, so that list view keeps its position and size, and only text view above shrinks and moves down to the list like in this picture below.

[image]

How can I accomplish this? I am okay with any layout type, I just used RelativeLayout code above as an example.

It would be easy if list view could have fixed size, but I want list view to take as much space as possible, and after activity is created I want it to stay in place and not change its size.

Comment: One solution that came to my mind is to create two textviews, and to anchor second smaller textview above the list and set it visibility to false. Then later when text has to change, I would just set visibility of first textview to false and visibility of second textview to true. But this is very dirty solution, plus I am not sure if layout will respect position constraints related to hidden items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) with [guideline](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) to tell your list view and your text view exactly where to be on your screen (It will be responsive to all screen sizes).

**It Will look something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline31" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tes"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline31"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline31"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And now your layout will look the same with long text or short text for the title:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is ok solution, thanks Tamir. Only negative side of it is that I would have to set fixed percentage value for the guideline, where instead I would like guideline to be just below the textview with its starting text.

Comment: You can chane your textview heigyt to wrap content, try this and if this wont work i will give you an example

Answer (score -1):

just add this line in your textview xml   `android:maxLines="1"`

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```